# Transform subject ID across groups that vary in size

Tags: r, dataframe

A MWE is as follows:
I have 3 groups with 2, 4, and 3 subjects consecutively. So I have:

```
library(dplyr)
Group <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
Subject_ID <- c(1, 2, 1 ,2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
df <- rbind(Group, Subject_ID)
```

Since the subjects in different groups are different subjects, so I want the subject ID be unique for each subject in the dataset. What I did was as follows:

```
Num_Subjects <- (length(unique(filter(df, Group == 1)$Subject)),
                 length(unique(filter(df, Group == 2)$Subject)),
                 length(unique(filter(df, Group == 3)$Subject)),
) 
# Then I defined a summation function to calculate how many subjects there are in all previous groups. 
sumfun <- function(x,start,end){
      return(sum(x[start:end]))
}

# Then I defined another function that generates a new subject ID for each subject in each group. 
SubjIDFn <- function(x, i) {
      x %>% filter(Session == i) %>% mutate(
            Sujbect = Subject + sumfun(Num_Subjects, 1, i-1)
      )
}
# Then I loop this from group 2 to group 3,
for (i in 2:3) {
      df.Corruption.WithoutS1 <- SubjIDFn(df.Corruption.WithoutS1, i)
}
```

Then the data set has zero observations. I don't know where it went wrong, and I don't know what is the smart solution to this problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're a bit overshooting it... If `Subject_ID` is unique within groups, you may just go with:

```
library(dplyr)
Group <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
Subject_ID <- c(1, 2, 1 ,2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3)
df <- bind_cols(Group=Group, Subject_ID=Subject_ID)
df %>% mutate(unique_id = paste(Group, Subject_ID, sep="."))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Group Subject_ID unique_id
  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>    
1     1          1 1.1      
2     1          2 1.2      
3     2          1 2.1      
4     2          2 2.2      
5     2          3 2.3      
6     2          4 2.4      
7     3          1 3.1      
8     3          2 3.2      
9     3          3 3.3
```

Note that I used `bind_cols` instead of `rbind` to have a dataframe instead of a matrix.

Comment: This is very helpful! Smart! I was trying to give each subject an integral ID, but it does not have to be. Another question, can I have a for loop within a mutate function?

Comment: I have never tried to use loops with mutate, and I do not think it is possible. However, I have learned from the wisdom of this community that loops are almost always a bad idea. File another question and provide the details of what you need to do.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! I later achieved my purpose with `group_by() %>% mutate()`.